# Create a meeting or calendar item using Domino Data Service(REST service)

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus

I am trying to book a mail room using Domino Data service.Can anybody please guide me in which form i have to create a document?
I am using 9.0.1 of Lotus Domino.

Comment: If you are using the REST data service to book a room in the Resource Reservation database, you could try creating a document based on the Reservation form.  However, that could get complicated.  Even if you succeed, you will bypass the core scheduling logic and you risk double booking the room.  Your question doesn't have a lot of details, but if appropriate to your use case, it might be better to use the REST calendar service (also in 9.0.1).   That would at least leverage the core scheduling logic.  I suggest rephrasing the question.  Maybe tell us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Thanks Dave.I am trying my application to integrate with domino.The usecases what i am looking for is all the operations CRUD of the normal and recurrence meeting .But the problem with REST calendar service is i have to pass each user's cred while accessing the service, i have only username , i don't have password of each user.Thats why i was trying the REST Data service where i can pass only one user credentials.If you help on this that will be great.

Comment: I don't see how the data service solves the password problem.  Please describe the use cases in more detail (e.g. User A invites Users B & C and Room D to a meeting).  I strongly recommend you edit the question itself.  That way other folks don't have to dig through the comments.

Comment: Thanks Dave.For Calendar service you need that user's credentials and for domino data service you can  create any one user in the domino and use the same for accessing from the client.My Usecase is all the CRUD operations for Normal as well as Recurrence meeting but the problem is i don't have user's password stored in my application.

Comment: Not true.  The authentication model is the same for both REST services.  If you can't authenticate the data service request with an identity that has access to the target mail file, then you won't be able to create an event.

Comment: Belated followup to clarify something Dave said: You will NOT double book a room if you try just creating a raw reservation doc.  At best you will create a document that the Rooms and Resource Manager will not process and you simply do not get the room even though you think you did.  If you tried to get clever and try to bypass the RnRMgr task, the reservation will not actually happen and someone else could get the room later.

Answer (score 1):

Domino Access Services provides a special API for calendar. You need to use the Calendar events POST (available since 9.0.1, which is you are using) as described [in the documentation](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM%20Domino%20Access%20Services%209.0.1#action=openDocument&res_title=Calendar_events_POST&content=apicontent)

JSON event representation is also described [here](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM%20Domino%20Access%20Services%209.0.1#action=openDocument&res_title=JSON_representation_of_an_event_das901&content=apicontent) with samples.