# Updating a Domino room reservation using the Domino Data API

Tags: rest, lotus-domino

We are integrating another application with Domino using the Domino REST API from [here](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM%20Domino%20Access%20Services%209.0.1#action=openDocument&content=catcontent&ct=api)

We are able to update the details of the room reservation but it doesn't release the availability of the room from the updated date/time

For instance, if someone booked a room for a meeting from 9am - 10am and it ended at 9.30am, our application can update the EndDateTime of the document but the room is still blocked in the resource calendar till 10am.

How do we properly update the room reservation?

Answer (score 1):

Booking a room with the data API is tricky.  You need to understand every detail of the data model in the reservation database.  I recommend using the REST calendar API instead of the data API.

For more details, see the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42719968/create-room-reservations-using-domino-data-services-rest-api).

Comment: yes, i actually applied this solution and it works fine. Found an issue though, the next booking would only be 5-15mins from the previous booking if i end the booking using the calendar API