# IBM Domino 10 - integrating with Resource Reservations via Domino Data Services API

Tags: api, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

We're trying to integrate with IBM Domino via REST API to pull out information about reservations/events in a specific room and also be able to create new events/reservations remotely. We already integrated with other services such as Microsoft Exchange, but IBM seems to be the toughest of them all.
I studied deeply into it and read thousands of articles & stack overflow questions, and got pretty far but still can't make any real use out of it.

What I currently plan on doing is this:

- Pull information about reservations from /api/data/collections/name/($Reservations) or ($Calendar)
- Create events/reservations using the documents api, POSTing to /api/data/documents?form=Reservation, I already tried doing it and my reservation even showed in Domino Admin (not in Notes client though), but it had some errors (probably just some json problem on my side)

While it looks kinda clear and easy, it really isn't. I have a few questions:

1. How can I get reservations/calendar for a **specific** room? ($Calendar) returns all events in the database, not even including in which room it is, to get that information I would need to additionally query each reservation by it's unid and that would probably kill the entire app
2. Is there any way I could filter/search the /api/data/documents to return only documents whose `form` field has a value of `Reservation` or any other value? This way I could get all the reservation documents without querying each of the documents directly (/api/data/documents only returns the href to the document without any interesting data), I wouldn't also need to additionally enable DAS for each view I want to use.
3. What are the fields like `$25` returned in the json, and how can I know what's their purpose if they don't have any real name? They often contain interesting data, such as the room name.

I also looked into the FreeBusy api service, and it's pretty interesting and I could easily use it to look for reservations (/busytimes) in the room I want, if it ever returned what resource/reservation is causing the busy time. It just shows the start and end time, nothing else..

I also read suggestions that one should create a 'main' user to handle the reservations and use his calendar api (/api/calendar/events), but afaik it can't be done that way.
However I tried creating events in the users calendar in specified room, and kinda got it to work by adding the following attendee in the json |(PHP syntax, actually):

```
'organizer' => [ 'email' => 'admin/test@test.com' ],
'attendees' => [
    [
        'role' => 'req-participant',
        'userType' => 'room',
        'status' => 'accepted',
        'rsvp' => true,
        'email' => 'testroom@test.com',
    ],
],
```

But it doesn't really get displayed in the room reservations, unlike normal events created in IBM Notes. It also cannot be edited or deleted in IBM Notes, and it has "Accepted: " in front of the subject, and it says "attendance is delegated for admin". To delete it, I need to delete it via API through its unid directly. x-lotus-noticetype is being set to A so I guess it's not being treated as a meeting but as an notice, no idea why though.

I'd really like some help or suggestions on how I could get this working, are there any other ways that would have any sense?

**Edit:**
After struggling a lot and reading Dave's reply, I think it would be a good solution to have a single user that would do the reservations via calendar api, because the direct data api probably won't work. I could just only pull the list of all reservations from Rooms database ($Calendar) or ($Reservations) view, or make some sort of my own view.
**However!** I cannot get the calendar method to work on my local IBM Domino server. Dave pointed to me that I need to specify a valid email (internet address) of the organizer, so I set my user's internet address to `testmail@test.test` (test.test is mapped to 127.0.0.1 in the hosts file). Now as soon as I try to use that address like that:

```
"organizer": {
    "email": "testmail@test.test"
}
```

I cannot even create the event/reservation (through `/mail/admin.nsf/api/calendar/events`), it's returning 500 internal error with cserror 1026, and Domino logs

```
[CS API]> Error | calendarapi.c(379) : There was an error sending out notices to meeting participants. (0x8E4)
Error connecting to server test/test: The remote server is not a known TCP/IP host.
```

So it has a problem with sending the notice, and doesn't create the event at all. I thought it may not work with localhost, so I set my users email to an external mail service, and I even received the email, but the event was still created incorrectly (`x-lotus-noticetype A` is being added automatically and overrides whatever I send as the value), it's not visible in the Room Reservations database.

Here's the json object of an event created via Notes client:

```
  "events": [
    {
      "href":"\/mail\/admin.nsf\/api\/calendar\/events\/2B35FABBC50EA4D0C12583BC002E26FA-Lotus_Notes_Generated",
      "id":"2B35FABBC50EA4D0C12583BC002E26FA-Lotus_Notes_Generated",
      "summary":"Notes client meeting",
      "location":"Test room\/Test site@test",
      "start": {
        "date":"2019-03-13",
        "time":"09:30:00",
        "tzid":"Central European Standard Time"
      },
      "end": {
        "date":"2019-03-13",
        "time":"10:30:00",
        "tzid":"Central European Standard Time"
      },
      "class":"public",
      "transparency":"opaque",
      "sequence":0,
      "last-modified":"20190313T082436Z",
      "attendees": [
                {
          "role":"chair",
          "status":"accepted",
          "rsvp":false,
          "displayName":"admin\/test",
          "email":"testmail@test.test"
        },
                {
          "role":"req-participant",
          "userType":"room",
          "status":"needs-action",
          "rsvp":true,
          "displayName":"Test room\/Test site",
          "email":"room@test.test"
        }
      ],
      "organizer": {
        "displayName":"admin\/test",
        "email":"testmail@test.test"
      },
      "x-lotus-broadcast": {
        "data":"FALSE"
      },
      "x-lotus-notesversion": {
        "data":"2"
      },
      "x-lotus-appttype": {
        "data":"3"
      }
    }
  ]
```

As you can see, Notes is able to create the event with `testmail@test.test` successfully.

Now here's an event created with my API, but with `admin/test@test.test` as the organizer's email (because normal email doesn't let me create the event):

```
 "events": [
    {
      "href":"\/mail\/admin.nsf\/api\/calendar\/events\/E1D1F752203FC2DFC12583BC002FCB12-Lotus_Auto_Generated",
      "id":"E1D1F752203FC2DFC12583BC002FCB12-Lotus_Auto_Generated",
      "summary":"Api reservation test",
      "location":"Test room\/Test site@test\r\nCN=Test room\/O=Test site",
      "description":"API Generated event\r\n",
      "start": {
        "date":"2019-03-20",
        "time":"11:00:00",
        "utc":true
      },
      "end": {
        "date":"2019-03-20",
        "time":"15:00:00",
        "utc":true
      },
      "class":"public",
      "transparency":"opaque",
      "sequence":0,
      "last-modified":"20190313T084201Z",
      "attendees": [
                {
          "role":"chair",
          "status":"accepted",
          "rsvp":false,
          "displayName":"admin\/test",
          "email":"testmail@test.test"
        },
                {
          "role":"req-participant",
          "userType":"room",
          "status":"needs-action",
          "rsvp":true,
          "displayName":"Test room\/Test site",
          "email":"room@test.test"
        }
      ],
      "organizer": {
        "displayName":"admin\/test",
        "email":"testmail@test.test"
      },
      "x-lotus-broadcast": {
        "data":"FALSE"
      },
      "x-lotus-notesversion": {
        "data":"2"
      },
      "x-lotus-noticetype": {
        "data":"A"
      },
      "x-lotus-appttype": {
        "data":"3"
      }
    }
  ]
```

As you can see, the organizer's & chair emails were automatically updated by Lotus to `testmail@test.test`, and theorethically everything should work but it doesnt. In Notes, I see the event as 'Accepted: Api reservation test' and I cannot modify things like the room, or don't have the option to delete it from right click menu (I can delete it with Del keyboard button though)
The only difference is that `x-lotus-noticetype` get's added, and I don't even know why

**Edit 2:**
I got it to work! Dave pointed that I may have some configuration issue, so I re-installed the server & setup everything again (including the mail services), I used `admin@test.test` and the meeting was succesfully created & added to the room reservations. Server console only showed that the message was delivered.
HOWEVER! I was able to create as many **identical** meetings as I wanted, they weren't added to the reservations database but they were succesfully created in my calendar (with the room assigned to them) without any errors (not even in the sever console), this is obviously bad. Is there any way to check (externally, through API) if the reservation was created succesfully, and prevent it's creation if the room is busy at that moment? Notes client prompts an error when the room is busy. I could probably use FreeBusy api, however that would require another HTTP request before each reservation attempt, but if that's the only way then I'll just take it. I see that the `status` field of the attendeed room is set to `declined`, but the response from POST still contains `needs-action` so I'd need to do some delayed request once again to check if the status has changed to declined or not.

Also, while it works, I still don't know how I could obtain a list of reservations in a selected room? The already existing views in Reservations database don't give many details, and they need to be exclusively enabled DAS services in order to work. Is there any other way that could work properly?

Another thing is, is there any way I could get current user's email address to use for the reservations, or can I only 'hardcode' it manually? Same goes for room's email. Currently, I need to have:

- User name
- User password
- User mail database (`/mail/admin.nsf/`)
- User email
- Room email

and if I'd want to read some data from the Reservations database directly, then I'd also need to have the path to that database. This isn't really user-friendly, I'd like to automate some things if possible. Otherwise the integration may be impossible to make.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow everything, but let's focus on what happens when the organizer is `testmail@test.test`. You said you see this error in the log: `There was an error sending out notices to meeting participants.` That's actually a good sign. It means the API is attempting to send a notice to the room. Have you tried creating a similar meeting in the Notes client? In other words, login as the admin user, create a meeting on the admin's calendar, and invite just the room. If the room doesn't receive the invitation, you have a configuration problem.

Comment: I tried it with Notes client, and while it succesfully creates the meeting and I can see the reservation in the database, server console also outputs errors: ```[C&S]> ERROR | Release 10.0.1 | csauto.cpp(830) : The remote server is not a known TCP/IP host. (0x1C63)
[0A6C:0002-1D60] 03/13/2019 04:16:45 PM  Error connecting to server test/test: The remote server is not a known TCP/IP host.
[0A6C:0002-1D60] 03/13/2019 04:16:45 PM  RnRMgr: Error processing reservation document (UNID OFDCB24AA7:47DB8DFA-ONC12583BC:0053EA00) in database Rooms.nsf```

Comment: However, when I delete the meeting for example, server logs `Router: Message 00547A1D delivered to Test room/Test site`, when deleting meetings created from API (invalid ones, that didnt invite the room) it logs that message was delivered, then a `csprof.cpp(473) : Entry not found in index (0x404)` followed by another `error processing reservation document`

Comment: Another interestign thing is, when sending a POST (that fails) via api, I also see following: ` [CS API]> Fixup UID->Apptunid bytes via ODS: 1 (Old method: 0, Ini: 1)` which is followed by errors from above

Comment: If the server cannot autoprocess an invitation originating from the Notes client, it won't be able to autoprocess an invitation from the calendar API. Sorry, but you have multiple problems to solve. I would start with the csauto.cpp error: `Error connecting to server test/test: The remote server is not a known TCP/IP host`. Without knowing more about your configuration, I don't have any guesses about that.

Comment: Dave, I got it to work thanks to your suggestion, however I still have some other problems. I made another edit to my original question, I'd appreciate if you checked it out. Thanks.

Comment: Q: "Is there any way to check ... if the reservation was created succesfully, and prevent it's creation if the room is busy at that moment?" A: You can use the freebusy API to check if a room is busy before you book it. The Notes client doesn't use the freebusy API directly, but it uses the same underlying code. And as you have already anticipated, even if you check before you book, it's still possible for the room to decline the invitation. If the room declines, the participant status should automatically get updated.

Comment: The R&R system is not designed like a user Calendar where you stuff Accepted reservations onto the calendar and they just appear as meetings.  As of R7, users create requests and the Rooms & Resource Manager task makes the final decision.  As part of that decision it will make the proper doc changes and update busytime.  That is why you are still not seeing what you expect.  You are stuffing in "Accepted" reservations but the system does not agree with you.  Dave's linked answer below is probably the best approach for you to take if you are using just REST APIs.

Comment: One reason you see duplicates on your calendar could be because you specify yourself as an attendees.  You should not need to do that if you are the Organizer since it is going onto your Calendar as part of the call.  If you look at a meeting created using Notes you will not see your name in the RequiredAttendee item.  Explicitly adding yourself could be causing you to receive workflow notices (e.g. a ghosted invite) when you do not want or need.  Try simply using just the room and any other users names in your attendees array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reservation database was designed to manage reservations either (1) directly through it's own UI, or (2) indirectly by auto-processing notifications from calendar users. By using the DAS data API, you are asserting you can manage reservations (3) programmatically -- by manipulating the low-level document items. You might get this to work, but I don't think the reservation database was designed with that in mind.

That's why I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42729877/1192402) is the best option. It leverages auto-processing (#2 above) and saves you from dealing with the internal design of reservation documents. If you use this approach, you should give the DAS calendar API a list of `attendees` like this:

```
  "attendees":[
    {
      "role":"req-participant",
      "userType":"room",
      "status":"needs-action",
      "rsvp":true,
      "email":"room@mycorp.com"
    }
  ]
```

In other words, `status` must be `"needs-action"` -- not `"accepted"` as shown in your original post. Also, make sure you are using the correct email address for both the organizer and the target room. The above example shows an Internet-style address for the room, but administrators don't always give a room an Internet address.

Comment: I saw that answer too and I tested it, with both accepted and needs-action. The email is correct, I set it myself and it's the same as in an event created from Notes client. When I send a POST with a room, it's not even being displayed correctly in Notes, it looks more like some sort of a notice. The generated json in /api/calendar/events is also slightly different (api event has x-lotus-noticetype: "A" and x-lotus-room is "CN=Test room/O=Test site", while Notes generated event has no noticetype and x-lotus-room is "Test room/Test site@test'. The event is not visible in Reservations database

Comment: I think the problem is the email address of the organizer (`admin/test@test.com`).  That's a Notes-style address. Have you tried using the organizer's Internet address? Also, have you tried using the calendar API to invite a user (not a room) to a meeting? I would get that working first. Then modify the POST request to invite a room instead.

Comment: I updated my question with more information, I tried setting a specific email address to the organzier but then I cannot even create the event, and when passing `admin/test@test` it kind of worked but the event is still created incorrectly and isn't existing in the Room Reservation database

Comment: @AJCole, it sounds like you have made progress. When you have a minute, please accept this answer. Thanks.

Comment: @AJCole: Enable debugging in the RnRMgr task by setting the INI DEBUG_RNRMGR=31.  That will generate plenty of debug output from the task.  You may want to also set CSLogAutoprocess=1 and CSReportErrors=1 to get debug output from the underlying C&S autoprocessing code that R&R uses for request processing.  After setting the INIs try a test and see what debug output shows on the console.  There should be something useful that can help figure out what is wrong w/the requests that are going to R&R.